# Redirect Issue for referral system when fetching URL data

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, mysqli

I have created a script for users to invite a friend using a email address, the email address and a randomly generated 10 character string 'inviteCode' is sent to a table called 'referrals'.

The invited person then receives an email with a URL link that contains their email and their unique inviteCode;  http://website.com/register.php?email=email&inviteCode=1234567890

When the user clicks on the link the page register.php should then check the URL and if they data is valid in the 'referrals' table. If so then I have an include line to add the register form, if not then they are redirected. The point is nobody can access register.php unless they have been invited and sent a link.

At the moment the page keeps redirecting to index.php;

Register.php script:

```
<?php 

  include 'config.php';

if (isset($_GET['email'],$_GET['inviteCode'])) {

$mysqli     = new Mysqli(/* your connection */);
$email      = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$inviteCode = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['inviteCode']);
$sql                = "SELECT email,inviteCode FROM referrals WHERE email='".$email."' AND inviteCode='".$inviteCode."'";
$query      = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {  //check if values are correct and available in database
    echo 'lol';
}
else
     {
    echo  'no';
          exit;
     }
}
else
    {
 echo 'problem'; //Page not accessible if neither email nor referral entered
    }

?>
```

I replaced the first if statement with:

```
if(!isset($_GET['email']) || !isset($_GET['inviteCode'])) {
    die(header('Location: index.php'));
} else
```

And I receive a blank page with no errors. I believe there may be something wrong with the email and invite code not being set.

Any help on this would be much appreciated (Y) thanks.

Comment: At each of those redirects, change them to a `die(random message);` just to see which condition is throwing the redirect.

Comment: I do have a sneaking suspicion that its the `if($mysql->num_rows)`

Comment: @Darren the second else statement seems to be forcing the redirect; when I take it out the script does not include the file, also am I even checking the URL string; because if I manually enter /register.php I can access the page; I should be getting redirected.

Comment: @Darren I do apologise, I am still just getting a blank page when visiting the page. I didn't think it would have so many bugs, just a simple if and else statement if the URL matches the table data

Answer (score 0):

You should really be looking at handling the errors first. Try something like this:

```
if(!isset($_GET['email']) || !isset($_GET['inviteCode'])) {
    die(header('Location: index.php'));
} else {
    $mysqli = new Mysqli(/* your connection */);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
    $inviteCode = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['inviteCode']);
    $sql = "SELECT email,inviteCode FROM referrals WHERE email='$email' AND inviteCode='$inviteCode'";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) { //check if values are correct and available in database
        include'register-form.php';
    } else {
        die(header('Location: index.php'));

    }
}
```

---

**Breakdown**

The `if` block checks to see if `GET[email]` or `GET[inviteCode]` are **not** set. if that is the case, kill the app with `die()` and redirect the user to `index.php`.

The second change is this line:

```
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
```

That will check to ensure the rows returned are more than **`0`** (meaning there are actually rows returned.) Because you were just testing the presence of the `$query->num_rows` before.

**Another Note:**

Turn on error reporting, it will help you emensly during debugging:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

---

You could alternatively change your sql query to select the `COUNT(id)` and check if that is greater than 0, but that seems like overkill for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply (Y) I have edited my post, I have tested your script - I receive a blank page ( A bracket or semi colen must be missing ) will come back.

Comment: @JSK Yeah please let me know what the outcome is!

Comment: I am not to sure If I am being blind or there is another issue, however I added **if(!isset($_GET['email']) || !isset($_GET['inviteCode'])) {
    die(header('Location: index.php'));
} else** & I already had error reporting on. I receive no errors and the page is just blank, I am not to sure if that is because the app is killed and not redirected or smaller error.

Comment: Am I even checking the URL string ? I may have confused myself with what should be a simple script

Answer (score 0):

Do this to find out if anything is being returned by your query:

Start by making sure that the connection to your database is succeeding:

```
$mysqli       = new Mysqli(/* your connection */);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$email        = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
```

Add that then let us know the results afterward, also provide specific error messages.

To debug your num_rows, replace this:

```
$query        = $mysqli->query($sql);

  if ($query->num_rows) //check if values are correct and available in database
    {
     include'register-form.php';
    }
```

With this:

```
$query        = $mysqli->query($sql);

$count = $query->num_rows;
print $count;
exit;

  if ($query->num_rows) //check if values are correct and available in database
    {
     include'register-form.php';
    }
```

If it shows 0, I have a suspicion it is because your sql statement needs to be concatenated.

```
"SELECT email,inviteCode FROM referrals WHERE email='".$email."' AND inviteCode='".$inviteCode."'";
```

Comment: Sorry I am still learning, I was wondering where exactly would I use that script, would it be at the top of the page or at the end of mine ? I have concatenated my statement just incase

Comment: It's ok, we've all been there. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really do appreciate it. I have received two errors, Undefined variable and trying to get property of non-object. This must be for the use of 'num_rows' - therefore I am presuming I am not returning anything that is why my script falls through to the last else statement.

Comment: I have edited my script, still seems to be no change with no errors appearing. And I just get the last echo, 'problem'. Must be something wrong with checking the table with the URL